# Select multiple files in react with refs

Tags: reactjs, file, fileapi

i am trying to select multiple files with react but my attempts failed
i want user to be able to select multiple files to upload next but my code can get only one file when i try to add second file, old file is replaced by new one

i have tried to add `multiple` attribute to my input element and also `accept="image/*` but non of them worked. currently i keep trying with `multiple`. here is my current code

...

```
  handleFile(e){
        let images = this.imgRef.current.files
        console.log(Array.from(images))
}
```

...

```
 <input type="file" name="images" id="imgid" className="imgcls" ref={this.imgRef} onChange={this.handleFile} style={{ display: "none" }} multiple/>
```

i want to log every file info but this is what i get instead

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxJs6.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need refs to access files. You can do it simple from the event received on change, like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  handleFile(e) {
    console.log(e.target.files)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input type="file" name="images" id="imgid" className="imgcls" onChange={this.handleFile} multiple/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: but i want to send that file later to server

Comment: You can save the files in state, like so:

this.setState({
  files: e.target.files
});

Comment: are you sure about that?

Comment: @ilia1 I believe I am having a similar issue.  I have a component with 5 child components that each render a file input.  The first component works as expected, but whenever I try to upload a second image using any of the other file inputs, React is associating the change with the first one and replacing that image.  I have tried using refs, `event.target`, state.  Nothing seems to change the behavior.

Comment: Did you try storing each file in a separate state variable?